# Aiogram. How to send message without sound?

Tags: telegram, chatbot, aiogram

I can [send message without sound](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZY8a.jpg). Can bot send message without sound using Aiogram?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Aiogram supports the `disable_notification` option.

For example, on a `reply`<sup>[[docs]](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/telegram/types/message.html?highlight=reply#aiogram.types.message.Message.reply)</sup> on `/start`:

```py
@dp.message_handlers(commands=['start'])
async def welcome(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply(text="No sound!", disable_notification=True)
```